# Evolution fails to connect to my Google calendar

Tags: synchronization, calendar, evolution, google, gmail

I've configured 2-Step Verification with my Google accont (under https://myaccount.google.com/security). Emails  with OAuth 2 seem to come through fine but I keep getting

```
"Failed to connect calendar “my.mail@gmail.com : MyName” 
Data source “MyName” does not support OAuth 2.0 authentication
```

and

```
Failed to connect address book “my.mail@gmail.com : Contacts”
```

why is this and how can I fix that?

I'm using Evolution 3.34.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fix" that worked for me was to give up on `Evolution` and I switched to using `Thunderbird` instead

Answer (score 0):

Im using Gnome and I could not add my GMail calendar from Evolution, but when I added Google through *Online accounts* under *Settings* (I am using Gnome 43 in Arch), it added it and it worked then in Evolution.

So my suggestion is to try adding Google from the *Online accounts* in *Settings*.

Comment: What type of calendar did it set up for you in Evolution? CalDav? Google? On the Web? Do you have more detail on the configuration? I tried all, but best I could do was CalDav, which worked read only.